# How do I reset bitcoin regtest mode?

Tags: regtest

Does anyone know how to reset everything in regtest mode?
I want to reset my balance and all transactions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the Bitcoin Core datadir:

- Linux `~/.bitcoin/regtest` directory.
- Windows `%appdata%\bitcoin\regtest` directory.
- MacOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/regtest` directory.

Comment: That works on unix systems.

Comment: Same folder on windows, just it’s in `%appdata%\bitcoin\regtest` instead.

Comment: Add it to the answer please.

Comment: Documentation is here: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode